# What/how does C++ delete operator work

Tags: c++

When we call delete on a pointer it calls the destructor of the object, but after the destructor it frees the memory the object was pointing to. If we overwrite the delete operator in a class, how would we do the same thing the original delete operator does with actually freeing the memory?

I'm thinking in terms of garbage collecting and smart pointers. Is it possible to have the default delete functionality of actually freeing the memory somehow (copy/paste the default delete operator code) if we overwrite a classes delete operator?

Yes, I'm just playing around with bastardizing C++. This isn't really for anything specific. Just trying to understand the possibilities around this.

I hate templated smart pointers and would love to try and implement smart pointers that allow you to still use the normal delete operator and no templated classes to wrap the pointer into.

Comment: +1 for "bastardizing C++" !

Comment: Well, google for "placement new" and delete. It's possible to create a global `operator new` that somehow registers a pointer with something. I don't think you can shove extra data or hooks into that pointer (for GC monitoring) and I doubt you can convince it to return a transparently wrapped pointer (to auto return smart_pointers). What do you have against the templated smart pointers? The whole point of them to eliminate the need to use `delete`. If you must use `delete`, then you may as well use raw pointers because you'll have all the same issues.

Comment: *"I hate templated smart pointers and would love to try and implement smart pointers that allow you to still use the normal delete operator"* Mother of God, why why why? Are you kidding me?

Comment: Why? I feel like it would be more natural to the language that if I have a pointer I called new to get that I eventually call delete to "free"?

Comment: To keep a pointer alive if multiple references exist to it. Let's say a pointer is created and then stored in 3 different classes. Class 1 calls delete on the pointer (because that's how you free pointers), but if we cut between the actual delete we can see there are other references still and not actually delete the memory. Inside our delete if the ref count gets to 0 then we actually free the memory. If you remove templates then you could do this by getting inside delete and deciding if you should actually free memory or not for the object.It now looks like a normal pointer without templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How the delete operator frees memory depends on how the
corresponding new operator acquired it.  If you're implementing
class specific operators, you probably need to implement both
(or neither).  In this case, you can use `::operator new` to get
the memory, and `::operator delete` to free it.

If you're thinking of replacing the global operator new and
operator delete, you can use `malloc` or `free` to allocate.
Formally, these are the only functions guaranteed not to use
`new` and `delete` themselves (but it's a good bet that
functions like `memset` don't either).

If you're interested in garbage collection, of course, `operator
new` will allocate from the garbage collected arena, and
`operator delete` will be a no-op.  (I've done this using the
Boehm collector, and it works quite well.)  You can do this on
a class by class basis, or you can do it globally.  If you do
this, you do not have to `delete` except if your program logic
requires it. But be aware that the garbage collector will *not*
call your destructor.  If the destructor is trivial, or is only
used for memory management (and thus has been subsumed by the
garbage collector), this is fine, and this is often the case.

One thing that you cannot change is that the `new` operator will
call a constructor (assuming the type has a non-trivial one),
after having called `operator new`, and the `delete` operator
will call the destructor, before calling `operator delete`.

Comment: I guess I figured inside delete is where it called the destructor? I wanted to get before calling the destructor and freeing the memory in order to check a ref count value to see if the object has other references to it. If it doesn't then it would call the destructor and actually free the object memory. If other ref counts are out there then it wouldn't do anything but reduce the ref count by 1 and keep the object in memory since a pointer to it exists somewhere else.

Comment: @user441521 That's what a reference counted pointer does.  If you don't want it limited to pointers, you can use a function to do the same thing, e.g. `void MyClass::unuse() { -- myUseCount; if ( myUseCount <= 0 ) delete *this; }`.

Comment: I was able to get this working where in the destructor I check if ref count > 0 and if so bail out and don't free any members of the class. Inside delete I cast the param to my object and call Release() to reduce ref count, then if it's = I call the destructor again explicitly. That works, however this means the object itself never gets deleted. I need code to actually free the memory of the object inside my delete after I explicity call the destructor.

Comment: Interesting if I call free() on the void* passed into delete operator of my class it seems to work.

Comment: @user441521 All you've achieved there is a lot of undefined behavior, which will fail in some programs.  One the compiler calls your destructor, your object it finished.  The compiler knows that it no longer exists (and that any pointer to it is invalid) and may optimize in consequence.